# Error: Component definition is missing display name in _document.js file [Next Js]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

Hi I am using a Next Js App, where I have to make some changes in the `_document.js` page.
I have added a `getInitialProps` method where I am passing page props in the `_document.js` file.

While doing yarn.build I am facing an eslint issue.

```
./pages/_document.tsx
11:30  Error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
```

Is this because of `<App {...props} />` and I have to define a name for this component. Tried some things but not able to find the fix. Also I cannot disable the eslint checks,

Please help. Please find my `_document.js` code below -

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

  export default class MyDocument extends Document {
   static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    let pageProps = null;

    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => {
          pageProps = props.pageProps;
          return <App {...props} />;
        },
        enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
      });

     const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
     return { ...initialProps, pageProps };
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <Html lang="en">
         <Head>
           {/* head tags */}
         </Head>
         <body>
           {/* body tags */}
         </body>
       </Html>
     );
   }
  }
```